# Django Exception Type: ProgrammingError Exception Value: no existe la función sum(character varying)

Tags: django, postgresql

I got an error when i use postgresql

```
total = DetalleFacturas.objects.filter(IdFactura__Fecha__range=[fechainicio, fechafinal],
                                                   IdFactura__IdBodega__Vendedor__Email=request.user.email).aggregate(
                Sum('Total'))
```

And i have got this error:

```
ProgrammingError at /reportehelisa/
no existe la función sum(character varying)
LINE 1: SELECT SUM("DetalleFacturas"."Total") AS "sum" FROM "Detalle...
```

It's work fine in sqlite but postresql not work

Comment: It looks like `Total` is a `CharField`, so it makes no sense to sum up values in `CharField`s.

Comment: Thank's Willem, i try convert str to int and i got this: ` Sum(int('Total')))`  Error: `Invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Total'`

Comment: @FreddyDiaz: that tries to convert the string `'Total'` to an `int`. Why is this a `CharFIeld`? It makes no sense...

Comment: You are trying now to convert string 'Total' to integer, obviously failing. You should probably refactor your model (so that `Total` is some numeric field). If using symbols is intended, try `Sum(models.functions.Cast('Total', models.IntegerField()))` instead.

Comment: lol, Of course, the error is mine, I'm going to try with CAST, thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
I convert the model

```
Total = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
```

to this

```
Total = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```